# what is "additional section" in DNS and how it works?

Tags: dns, bind

When i use `dig`

```
$ dig www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59489
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     23  IN  A   69.171.247.71

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     124333  IN  NS  ns4.GOoGLE.cOM.
google.com.     124333  IN  NS  ns1.GOoGLE.cOM.
google.com.     124333  IN  NS  ns3.GOoGLE.cOM.
google.com.     124333  IN  NS  ns2.GOoGLE.cOM.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.google.com.     300146  IN  A   216.239.32.10
ns1.google.com.     308505  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:32::a
ns2.google.com.     303470  IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns2.google.com.     124333  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:34::a
ns3.google.com.     303470  IN  A   216.239.36.10
ns3.google.com.     124333  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:36::a
ns4.google.com.     302836  IN  A   216.239.38.10
ns4.google.com.     302716  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:38::a
```

There is a `ADDITIONAL SECTION`.

I know the structure of DNS packet is:

```
+---------------------+
| Header              |
+---------------------+
| Question            | the question for the name server
+---------------------+
| Answer              | Answers to the question
+---------------------+
| Authority           | Not used in this project
+---------------------+
| Additional          | Not used in this project
+---------------------+
```

But i don't know the detail of `ADDITIONAL SECTION`.

I mean, where `ADDITIONAL SECTION` comes from(authority server?) and what's it used for?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) that deals with DNS and specifically section 4.1 "Message Format".

You will read there:

> the additional records section contains RRs
> which relate to the query, but are not strictly answers for the
> question.

And also the various formats under 3.3 that explains which record will trigger specific "additional" treatment.

You  can also find in RFC 1034 sections 6.2 and 6.3 some examples of queries and replies where you will see how the Additional section is filled out.

Now to go back to your example, the problem is that you are not specificying explicitely which nameserver you query which means you get answer from the default recursive one.

In which case you see:

- in "Answer" the exact record for your query (dig does an `A` by default if you do not specify anything)
- in "Authority" you see what the recursive has learnt about which nameservers are authoritative for your record
- in "Additional" you get the IP addresses of the nameservers in previous section, especially here since you are in a "in-bailiwick" case (often known as "glues") so you (as a recursive nameserver) would have no way to connect the authoritative nameservers.

Let us redo the query directly using an authoritative nameserver, and then compare with another case:

$ dig google.com NS @a.gtld-servers.net

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> google.com NS @a.gtld-servers.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12149
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.google.com.     172800  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:34::a
ns2.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns1.google.com.     172800  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:32::a
ns1.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.32.10
ns3.google.com.     172800  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:36::a
ns3.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.     172800  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:38::a
ns4.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.38.10

;; Query time: 68 msec
;; SERVER: 192.5.6.30#53(192.5.6.30)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 03 19:23:20 EST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 287
```

So here we are asking one authoritative nameserver of the `.COM` zone to give us the nameservers of `google.com`. The result is similar to previously.

Let us query the same nameserver but for another domain:

```
$ dig ultradns.com NS @a.gtld-servers.net

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> ultradns.com NS @a.gtld-servers.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54105
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 10, ADDITIONAL: 5
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ultradns.com.          IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ultradns.com.       172800  IN  NS  pdns196.ultradns.com.
ultradns.com.       172800  IN  NS  pdns196.ultradns.net.
ultradns.com.       172800  IN  NS  pdns196.ultradns.org.
ultradns.com.       172800  IN  NS  pdns196.ultradns.info.
ultradns.com.       172800  IN  NS  pdns196.ultradns.biz.
ultradns.com.       172800  IN  NS  pdns196.ultradns.co.uk.
ultradns.com.       172800  IN  NS  ari.alpha.aridns.net.au.
ultradns.com.       172800  IN  NS  ari.beta.aridns.net.au.
ultradns.com.       172800  IN  NS  ari.gamma.aridns.net.au.
ultradns.com.       172800  IN  NS  ari.delta.aridns.net.au.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
pdns196.ultradns.com.   172800  IN  A   156.154.64.196
pdns196.ultradns.com.   172800  IN  AAAA    2001:502:f3ff::e8
pdns196.ultradns.net.   172800  IN  A   156.154.65.196
pdns196.ultradns.net.   172800  IN  AAAA    2610:a1:1014::e8

;; Query time: 72 msec
;; SERVER: 192.5.6.30#53(192.5.6.30)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 03 19:25:24 EST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 432
```

Pay close attention to the list of namservers in the "Authority" section and the ones having an `A`/`AAAA` record in the "Additional" section. You will realise that only those ending in `.com` or `.net` (because this is a special case where both of these TLDs are handled by the same registry) have IP addresses here because the authoritative nameservers for `.COM`/`.NET` know nothing about names and IP addresses in other TLDs.

This can be seem even more with this example:

```
$ dig aridns.com NS @a.gtld-servers.net

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> aridns.com NS @a.gtld-servers.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 2552
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;aridns.com.            IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
aridns.com.     172800  IN  NS  dns1.ausregistry.net.au.
aridns.com.     172800  IN  NS  dns1-1.ausregistry.net.au.
aridns.com.     172800  IN  NS  dns1-2.ausregistry.net.au.
aridns.com.     172800  IN  NS  dns2-1.ausregistry.net.au.

;; Query time: 68 msec
;; SERVER: 192.5.6.30#53(192.5.6.30)
;; WHEN: Mon Sep 03 19:28:07 EST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 139
```

No "Additional" section at all, because all nameservers are out of zone!

Answer (score 3):

The `ADDITIONAL SECTION` contains data that you did not explicitly ask for, but the server gave it to you anyway.

This can be used by servers to give answers to typical follow-up questions, because lookup patterns can be quite predictable. I.e. if you ask for an MX record, you are probably going to perform A lookups for the returned MX records next, and if the authoritative server happen to have those as well they can be returned to you directly without having to do one or more extra DNS round-trips.

In your specific example, since you asked for all resource types and got NS records, the same authoritative server also knew the A and AAAA records for those nameservers and thought it was helpful to give then to you.

As the internet draft **"Returning additional answers in DNS responses"** (https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-fujiwara-dnsop-additional-answers-00.html) summarizes it in the introduction:

> By providing multiple answers in single response, authoritative name servers can assist full-service resolvers in pre-populating their cache before stub resolvers or other clients ask for the subsequent queries. Apart from decreasing the latency for end users, this also decreases the total number of queries that full-service resolvers need to send and authoritative servers need to answer.

Comment: The document you quote is a draft specifying to answer more content that initially asked for, like giving the `AAAA` record when asking for `A`. This is **in addition** to what the core protocol specifices for this section, it was not planned to be used like that.

Comment: Besides the first sentence, the rest is unfortunately not really right. The Additional section has another specific use, see my answer. Answering an `A` record after a `MX` is an extension of the protocol, not it core. Do `dig MX stackoverflow.com` and you will see no additional section at all, as expected.

Comment: " the same authoritative server also knew the A and AAAA records for those nameservers and thought it was helpful to give then to you. " in that specific case; with all in-bailiwick nameservers , this authoritative server **had to** give you the IP addresses, because if it did not (for the recursive nameserver doing all this job), the nameserver will be unable to proceed and resolve the name as you hit a chicken and egg problem.